# Rails 3 Nested Resources: can't get form or pages to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working on a web app for social networking site but it seems as if getting my nested resources to work correctly is impossible. If you can help me out that would be great and I would be very thankful.

Here are my routes. I would like to have the url structure like mysite.com/username/photos /(new, edit, etc). The url structure is like so but I get an error when trying to access the forms or page. Down below I have posted what I have so far.

**routes.rb**

```
   resources :users do  
   resources :photos  
   end
```

**photo.rb**

```
belongs_to :users
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :photos, :foreign_key => "id", :dependent => :destroy
```

**_form.html.erb**
This form has an attachment using paperclip. There is a <% before statement I removed it because it would not show the entire code below on here.

```
 form_for(@photos,@user) :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

**photos_controller.rb**

```
 def new
  @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a before_filter to get the user, and the form posts to create, not new.  Your photo controller should look something like:

```
before_filter :get_user
...

def new
  @photo = @user.photos.build
end

def create
  @photo = @user.photos.build(params[:photo])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.save
      format.html {redirect_to [@user, @photo], notice: "Photo saved!"}
    else
      format.html {render action: "new"}
    end
  end
end
...
private
def get_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

Here, the before_filter grabs the user.  In nested routes, the parent resource ID will be in `params[:parent_id]` or in this case, `params[:user_id]`.  Then inside the create controller, you want to build a photo from the `@user.photos` collection.  This will automatically create the reference between the photo and the user.

Also, your form_for has the relations backwards.  It should be `form_for([@user, @photo]) ...`, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you and small errors. I have to start looking at my code more carefully. Thanks for pointing them out!

Answer (score 1):

Not certain that this is the problem but it appears that your `form_for` tag is in the wrong format.  You are closing the parentheses on the `form_for` tag after specifying your user, and thus it is ignoring the `:html` part.  I would try this:

```
<%= form_for([@photos, @user], :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

The `@photos` and `@user` must be passed in as an array.

Also, Not sure why the `@photos` param would be plural.  Shouldn't it be `[@photo, @user]`?  I may be wrong on that part though.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error that you get and where?

A couple things:
in `photo.rb`:

```
belongs_to :user
```

instead of `users`

Are you trying to create photos from `users#new` page? If so, try to look at `accepts_nested_attributes_for` usage:
in `user.rb`

```
has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
```

And then, on your `users#new` form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  # ... user attributes ...
  <%= f.fields_for :photo do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end%>
```

Also, consider using [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) instead of paperclip for your uploads. Here is the [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads). Good luck.

Comment: Thank! Figured it out after a while. I didn't update the controllers to include my new model. Also the video you've posted helped me alot thanks again!